# Android: Three dot icon and sub menu icon are not showing after clicking/expanding them

Tags: android, android-actionbar, optionmenu, appbar

I want to see three dot icon and sub menu icon even after expanding them.

First Picture not showing any icon:

[image]

Should be like this:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you see is the correct Material design for menus, since the [Material Design specifications](http://www.google.com/design/spec/layout/structure.html#structure-app-bar) says that:

> A menu is a temporary sheet of paper that always overlaps the app bar,
>   rather than behaving as an extension of the app bar.

This is an example of what Google Recommends.

[image]

However you can still place the Overflow Menu below the toolbar by creating a new style which defines your overflow menu. Add this `<item name="myOverflowMenu">@style/OverflowMenu</item>` to your style.

```
<style name="OverflowMenu" parent="Widget.AppCompat.PopupMenu.Overflow">
<item name="overlapAnchor">false</item>
<item name="android:dropDownVerticalOffset">?attr/actionBarSize</item>
<item name="dropDownVerticalOffset">?attr/actionBarSize</item>
<item name="android:overlapAnchor">false</item>    
</style>
```

Comment: I didn't know this. **A menu is a temporary sheet of paper that always overlaps the app bar, rather than behaving as an extension of the app bar.** I don't want to force. Thank you.

Comment: If the answered helped, please consider accepting it by clicking the tick icon next to the answer.

Comment: Glad to help! Cheers!

Comment: @Abhi `<item name="myOverflowMenu">@style/OverflowMenu</item>` where do we have put this line? It shows error, please complete and clear code.

Comment: @hasnain_ahmad You have place in the `styles.xml` file.

Comment: @Abhi I have put the `<style> .... </style>` in the `styles.xml`. But how to reference/call/set the `myOverflowMenu` for the menu items in xml or java class?

Comment: @hasnain_ahmad You don't have to call the style. The style will be added to the menu automatically as `myOveflowMenu` specified the parent as the menu widget.